Magento2 Add multiple configurable items into cart with same parent product
Magento2 multiply the qty of first item if add two configurable item into cart programmatically with same parent product.
$items = [
        [
            'child_id'=>'47',
            'parent_id'=>'62',
            'qty'=>1
        ],
        [
            'child_id'=>'48',
            'parent_id'=>'62',
            'qty'=>1
        ]
    ];

foreach($items as $item){
    if(isset($item['parent_id']) && !empty($item['parent_id'])){
        //$quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $product = $productModel->getById($item['parent_id']);
        $childProduct = $productModel->getById($item['child_id']);
        $productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
        $options = [];
        foreach($productAttributeOptions as $option){
            $options[$option['attribute_id']] =  $childProduct->getData($option['attribute_code']);
        }

        $objParam = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'product' => $product->getId(),
                'qty' => $item['qty'],
                'super_attribute' => $options
            ]
        );        
        $quote->addProduct($product, $objParam);
    } else {
        $product= $productModel->getById($item['child_id']);
        $quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
    }
}
$quote->save(); 

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you

To multiply the quantity of the first configurable item in the cart when adding two configurable items with the same parent product, you can modify the loop logic and check if a product with the same parent ID and configuration already exists in the cart. If it does, update its quantity instead of adding a new product.
This approach ensures the quantity is updated for the first item instead of adding multiple cart items for the same parent product.
$items = [
    [
        'product_id' => '47',
        'parent_id' => '62',
        'qty' => 1
    ],
    [
        'product_id' => '48',
        'parent_id' => '62',
        'qty' => 1
    ]
];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (isset($item['parent_id']) && !empty($item['parent_id'])) {
        $product = $productModel->getById($item['parent_id']);
        $childProduct = $productModel->getById($item['product_id']);
        $productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);

        // Prepare super attributes
        $options = [];
        foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $option) {
            $options[$option['attribute_id']] = $childProduct->getData($option['attribute_code']);
        }

        // Check if a similar item exists in the cart
        $isUpdated = false;
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $cartItem) {
            $cartProduct = $cartItem->getProduct();
            if ($cartProduct->getId() == $item['parent_id'] && $cartItem->getOptionByCode('super_attribute')) {
                $cartSuperAttributes = $cartItem->getOptionByCode('super_attribute')->getValue();
                $cartOptions = unserialize($cartSuperAttributes);

                // Compare super attributes to determine if it's the same item
                if ($cartOptions == $options) {
                    // Update quantity for the existing item
                    $newQty = $cartItem->getQty() + $item['qty'];
                    $cartItem->setQty($newQty);
                    $isUpdated = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // If not updated, add a new product to the cart
        if (!$isUpdated) {
            $objParam = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'product' => $product->getId(),
                    'qty' => $item['qty'],
                    'super_attribute' => $options
                ]
            );
            $quote->addProduct($product, $objParam);
        }
    } else {
        // For simple products
        $product = $productModel->getById($item['product_id']);
        $quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
    }
}
$quote->save();


My question was Magento increasing the quantity of first child product but I am adding different child product of same parent product. . So it should be two different item
